# Spring batch job with unique jobParamIncrementer

Tags: spring-batch

I've written a spring batch application for simple query. This works fine for first time with some job Id, but for next execution it requires new job id. For this wrote jobParamIncrementer class, still getting bean defn not found exception. I'm not exactly getting whats happening. Please help me out.

**Below is stack trace.**

```
Job Paramater {run.id=1370337260531}
Jun 4, 2013 2:44:20 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@10b9d04: startup date [Tue Jun 04 14:44:20 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 4, 2013 2:44:20 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Jun 4, 2013 2:44:20 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'uniqueJob': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.JobParserJobFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
Jun 4, 2013 2:44:21 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@ccc588: defining beans [dataSource,transactionManager,jdbcTemplate,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,jobRepository,jobLauncher,org.springframework.batch.core.scope.internalStepScope,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer,org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.CoreNamespacePostProcessor,step1,uniqueJob,e4XCountriesRowMapper,jobParamIncrementer,cursorReader,flatFileWriter]; root of factory hierarchy
Jun 4, 2013 2:44:21 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Jun 4, 2013 2:44:21 PM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher afterPropertiesSet
INFO: No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
Jun 4, 2013 2:44:21 PM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner start
SEVERE: Job Terminated in error: No bean named '{run.id=1370337260531}' is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '{run.id=1370337260531}' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:339)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574)
    at com.JobRunner.main(JobRunner.java:179)
Jun 4, 2013 2:44:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@10b9d04: startup date [Tue Jun 04 14:44:20 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 4, 2013 2:44:21 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@ccc588: defining beans [dataSource,transactionManager,jdbcTemplate,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,jobRepository,jobLauncher,org.springframework.batch.core.scope.internalStepScope,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer,org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.CoreNamespacePostProcessor,step1,uniqueJob,e4XCountriesRowMapper,jobParamIncrementer,cursorReader,flatFileWriter]; root of factory hierarchy
```

**below is applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">



    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://<ip>/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean> 
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean"> 
        <property name="databaseType" value="MYSQL"/>
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> 
         <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/> </bean>


    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>


        <!-- BD to CSV -->

    <!-- <batch:job id="sampleJob" incrementer="jobParamIncrementer"> -->
    <batch:job id="uniqueJob" incrementer="jobParamIncrementer">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="cursorReader" writer="flatFileWriter"
                    commit-interval="1000" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
    <bean id="e4XCountriesRowMapper" class="com.E4XCountriesRowMapper">
    </bean>
    <bean name="jobParamIncrementer" class="com.JobParamIncrementer">
    </bean>



    <bean id="cursorReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql" value="select * from e4x_countries" />
        <property name="rowMapper" ref="e4XCountriesRowMapper" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="flatFileWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
        <property name="resource"
            value="file:fileNme.txt" />

        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
                <property name="delimiter" value="," /> <!-- default -->

                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names"
                            value="countryCode,countryName,currencyCode,currencyName,currencySymbol" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

**JobParameterIncrementer.java**

```
public class JobParamIncrementer implements JobParametersIncrementer {
    public JobParameters getNext(JobParameters parameters) {
        System.out.println("got job parameters: " + parameters);
        /*if (parameters==null || parameters.isEmpty()) {
            return new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("run.id", 1L).toJobParameters();
        }*/
        return new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("run.id", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()).toJobParameters();
        /*long id = parameters.getLong("run.id",Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()) + 1;
        JobParametersBuilder jobParamBuilder  = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("run.id", id);
        return  jobParamBuilder.toJobParameters();*/

    }
}
```

**JobRunner(main class)**

```
public class JobRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JobParamIncrementer jobName = new JobParamIncrementer();
        try {
            String id=jobName.getNext(null)+"";
            System.out.println("Job Paramater "+id+"");
            CommandLineJobRunner.main(new String[] { "applicationContext.xml", id});
            System.out.println("DONE");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't pass the job name to the CommandLineJobRunner.
Try changing the call to CommandLineJobRunner.main in JobRunner.main() method to:

```
CommandLineJobRunner.main(new String[] { "applicationContext.xml", "uniqueJob", id});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved :) added below lines of code in application context

```
<bean id="jobExplorer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

and in JobRunner.java

```
CommandLineJobRunner.main(new String[] { "applicationContext.xml", "uniqueJob","-next"});
```

Thanks all for you time and help...

Comment: But now I want to run this by connecting to DB2 client, added credentials and Jars, nothing much change but getting following Exception :( pls help..

Comment: Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: DB2 SQL: SQLCODE: -204, SQLSTATE: 42704, SQLERRMC: DB2ADMIN.BATCH_JOB_SEQ
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.jd.e(jd.java:1664)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.jd.a(jd.java:1240)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.fb.h(fb.java:149)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.fb.a(fb.java:43)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.s.a(s.java:30)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.wb.g(wb.java:152)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.jd.n(jd.java:1220)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.jd.executeQuery(jd.java:508)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractSequenceMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(AbstractSequenceMaxValueIncrementer.java:69)
 ... 22 more